# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given django python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

i'm trying to list user from api and also using jwt authentication but when i run localhost:8000/api/ get this error:

```
_init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView,    TokenRefreshView




urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',views.UserViewSet, name = 'user_list'),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = User.object.all()
serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializers
```

Comment: You should add `.as_view()`, so `views.UserViewSet.as_view()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `ViewSet`, you need to [use **`.as_view()`** as well [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/):

> The method handlers for a `ViewSet` are only bound to the corresponding actions at the point of finalizing the view, **using the `.as_view()` method**.

In your `urlpatterns`, youthus need to use `.as_view()`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',views.UserViewSet.as_view(), name = 'user_list'),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```